# How do I centre n columns using CSS?

Tags: css

I currently have the following CSS for my 4 columns which might grow to 5 or 6 in the future:

```
<style>
.columns {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px red dotted;
    width: 90%;
}

.columns div {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    overflow:hidden;
    border: solid 1px;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
</style>

<div class="columns">
  <div>
    <h3>First</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>left</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Second</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>mid</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Third</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>right</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Fourth</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>far right</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to use what I have to centre all 4 columns in the middle of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got something workable after reading all the possible answers with minimum amount of hard-coded calculated values.  I've taken out the borders for simplicity:

```
.columns {
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
}

.columns div {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 22%;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-right: 4%;
}

.columns div.last {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Use `<div class="last">` in the last column.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to set a static width on .columns:

```
.columns {
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px red dotted;
}
```

You'll probably want to put a clearing div at the bottom of the document (after .columns) as well:

```
<div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Just to stretch out the .columns container (so your border goes the length of the columns).

**UPDATE**

If you're trying to strictly make a four column layout, then update .columns div as such:

```
.columns div {
    width: 160px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

The only real secret here is to take the total width of the container and divide by four. In the case I provide, 800/4 = 200 so each column has a total width (width + padding + margins) of 200px;

Comment: don't use a clearing div. use "min-height: 10px" instead. f IE6

Comment: will min-height stretch the border on his container div even though the divs inside are floated?

Comment: The gap between the right margin of the 4th column and the right border of div.columns is still present.  How do you make the 4 columns fill out div.columns evenly?

Comment: Updated the answer to take care of this as well.

Comment: For the columns div to be centered in old versions of Internet Explorer you will also need to have a text-align:center; on the columns' parent element.

Answer (score 0):

well, TECHNICALLY yes, but it requires you to set a width at some point, probably on your wrapper div. i don't know if it's possible to center dynamically-widthed (ie, 20% width) floated columns. if you set your wrapper div width to something, then you can set margins on your other columns to center them